# using enums across files without defining them in a header

Tags: c++, enums, header-files

for example I have
enu.cpp

```
enum ena{
    X, Y
};
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ena a = X;

}
```

how do I declare (not define) the enum in a header file so that I can use ena in main.cpp.

Please note that I don't want to define the enum in the header, but just want the compiler to know (through the header file) that the definition of the enum ena exists in some cpp file (in this case enu.cpp)

basically I want to forward declare an enum.

Comment: You can forward declare an `enum` just like any other type, and you can use it in the same ways as any other forward-declared type: you can create a pointer or reference to it, and you can use it as an argument type in the declaration of a function. There's nothing more that you can do without defining it.

Comment: The compiler doesn't really create any output from an enum definition. So the concept of having a definition in an other compile unit, and resolve it during linking doesn't actually make any sense. Variables of enum type on the other hand, can be `extern` like any other variable.